# No need to encrypt data for https?

Tags: security, ssl, https, cryptography, man-in-the-middle

I was monitoring web traffic from my Android mobile using a man-in-the-middle proxy. As part of this I installed a certificate (signed by my server) to my mobile and I could see all applications sending sensitive information like passwords as clear text.

I understand that SSL protocol takes care of establishing a secure communication, but does that eliminate the need to encrypt data?

Comment: data on the wire is encrypted. you're intercepting that data using an ssl proxy, basically, so yes, you'll be able to see anything. If you follow the news, this is no different than today's CNNIC blacklisting or the recent Lenovo Superfish fiasco.

Comment: Isn't that really security threat? If someone managed to install certificate, then all my data is compromised?

Comment: a certificate by itself does NOTHING. it's just some numbers. it's whatever apps are being used that are the threat.

Answer (score 0):

So there are really 2 questions here:

Does it eliminate the need to encrypt data *in all cases*? No.

Does it eliminate the need to encrypt data *in most cases*? Yes.

To understand those answers we need to talk about one important thing: key distribution.

How are you going to get the key to your user (the one making the request). If you have a reliable side-channel, then it's possible to send the key in the side channel. This means that any data encrypted and sent over TLS won't be decryptable even if the attacker can decrypt the TLS stream.

For the average website, there's no reliable side-channel. For the average network service there isn't one either (implementations like sshd simply make the best effort approach of "assume the first connection is good").

If your data is important enough to justify the side-channel distribution of keys (preferably offline), then the added encryption inside of TLS can protect you from certain attack vectors.

However, ask yourself if its worth it for your use case. All security is a tradeoff of usability and simplicity...